# Hidden text negative for Google spiders?

Tags: search, seo, adsense

I'm designing a website with several small articles. All articles have a visible `H1` headline, but the text is not visible. It's hidden from the beginning with jQuery. To view the text, I have a icon with a plus sign in the bottom of the article. With this design there will be less scrolling on mobile devices.

I'm just curious and wondering if this is bad when it comes to SEO and Google AdSense? Can the spider from Google index the website and read the text, despite that it's not visible on screen, but "visible" in the code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Possibly a better fit for [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. Hidden text is only an issue when it is done so for the express purpose of manipulating your rankings. Your content is available to both users and search engines alike so it is ok to do this.

Comment: OK thats great! I just thought the spiders would "read" the page the same way as human see it and not just the code and its content!?

Comment: Search engines see the code, not a screen, so as long as they can parse that content it is visible to them.